# Is there a standard notation for coding finite sets of numbers as numbers?

Tags: logic, notation, proof-theory

Hajek and Pudlak *Metamathematics of First-Order Arithmetic* use the Ackermann encoding of hereditarily finite sets, but they use no notation for codes.  They let the reader see from context when a number is functioning as a code. Alberto Policriti http://www.dmi.unict.it/~cilc2013/submissions/cilc20130_submission_24.pdf
writes $\mathbb{N}_A(x)$ for the Ackermann code for the hereditarily finite set $x$.

I would like to use some notation more explicit than the first and lighter than the second.  Say $\ulcorner x\urcorner$ or $\overline{x}$.  But I want something reasonably standard.  Is the corner quote notation usually used only for Godel numbering of terms and formulas?  Would overline be confused with some other concept?